# Problema con el efecto Ripple circular en botón sobre SubsamplingScaleImageView en Android"

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-button, back-button

**Descripción del Problema:**

Estoy enfrentando un problema con un botón en mi aplicación Android que no muestra el efecto Ripple circular al ser clickeado.

**Contexto:**

Mi interfaz de usuario consiste en una imagen de tipo SubsamplingScaleImageView que ocupa toda la pantalla, y encima de esta imagen he colocado un botón con el ID btnBack. Estoy utilizando la biblioteca SubsamplingScaleImageView de GitHub para manejar la visualización de imágenes de gran tamaño de manera eficiente.

**Problema:**

Cuando hago clic en el botón btnBack, el efecto Ripple circular no se muestra. Sin embargo, al eliminar la imagen de fondo y dejar solo el botón, el efecto Ripple funciona correctamente.

**Posible Causa:**

Creo que el problema puede estar relacionado con la superposición del botón sobre la SubsamplingScaleImageView, lo que podría estar interfiriendo con la visualización del efecto Ripple.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.davemorrissey.labs.subscaleview.SubsamplingScaleImageView
        android:id="@+id/subsamplingScaleImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:transitionName="imageTransition"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        android:foregroundGravity="center" />


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnBack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_back_arrow"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Capturas de Pantalla:

Adjunto capturas de pantalla que ilustran el problema. En la primera imagen, al hacer clic en btnBack, no se muestra el efecto Ripple circular. En la segunda imagen, al eliminar el fondo de SubsamplingScaleImageView, el efecto Ripple funciona como se espera.

[image: En esta imagen, estoy haciendo clic en btnBack pero no muestra ningún efecto riple circular..]

[image: En esta imagen, se eliminó el fondo de SubsamplingScaleImageView y al hacer clic en el botón puede ver el efecto deseado.]

Agradezco cualquier ayuda o comentario sobre cómo resolver este problema. ¡Gracias!

Saludos cordiales,

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!